# Rotation of a quad so that it's perpendicular to a sphere

Tags: opengl, 3d, three.js

In an OpenGL app I'm working on, I have a sphere of radius r and an array of lat/long points.

I want to render a sphere and then render a square at each lat/long. The piece I am stuck on is rotating the square so that for any location, it ends up perpendicular to the surface of the sphere - like a tangent.

The sphere is centered at the origin.

In pseudocode I have:

```
lat = rand( 180.0 ) - 90.0;
lng = rand( 180.0 );

phi = ( 90.0 - lat ) * PI / 180.0;
theta = ( 360.0 - lng ) * PI / 180.0;

x = radius * sin( phi ) * cos( theta );
y = radius * cos( phi );
z = radius * sin( phi ) * sin( theta );

square.setRotation( rx, ry, rz );
square.setPosition( px, py, pz );
```

I want to come up with values for rx, ry and rz. One of them should be 0 of course and I imagine the other 2 are connected to lat/lng but all the combinations I've tried have not worked.

JavaScript example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NZEBH/2/

Comment: How is your square oriented when the rotation is zero?

Comment: And what is the rotation order?

Comment: This is what i get if the values for setRotation are all 0 (http://i.imgur.com/Ghurv.png) - not sure what you mean by order of rotation. I *think* I can rotate on each axis individually so I can control the order. Or do you mean do I rotate before I set position?

Comment: Typically when a rotation is specified as three values, it indicates the amount of rotation about the X, Y, and Z axes, but the order that these rotations are applied affects the result.  It also matters whether the rotations are applied in fixed axes or the rotated axes.

Comment: Is that true if the rotations happen at the origin and the object is moved to its final position afterwards?

Comment: Yes.  You can find more info here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Comment: If you can post the code for how the square is drawn that would make it more clear.

Comment: I made a short demo in JavaScript that illustrates what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/NZEBH/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
mesh.lookAt( sphere.position );
```

See updated fiddle which is commented: http://jsfiddle.net/NZEBH/59/

Remember, if the face normal faces toward the center of the sphere, then you will have to set the material to THREE.BackSide or THREE.DoubleSide.

Comment: Many thanks WestLangley - I got the code I used from Camera::LookAt() - I didn't know that method existed on Mesh too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but using some code to make the camera look at a point, I came up with this to rotate the square and it appears to work as I want:

```
var target_vec = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
var rotation_matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
rotation_matrix.makeRotationX( phi );
rotation_matrix.makeRotationY( 0 );
rotation_matrix.makeRotationZ( theta );
rotation_matrix.lookAt( mesh.position, target_vec, mesh.up );
mesh.rotation.setEulerFromRotationMatrix( rotation_matrix, mesh.eularOrder );
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NZEBH/47/

Comment: That's a good way to do it, but the makeRotation calls are unnecessary.

Comment: How do I set the angles for rotation without those calls though?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions Vaughn - much appreciated.